# Why can't I add an answer?

Tags: support

I joined yesterday. I spent a few hours browsing to get the feel of things, then added an answer with some code, for which I got some reputation points.

Today, I asked for clarification on another question, which I now realise I'm not supposed to do. And yet, I can see hundreds of examples where folk ask for clarifications on bad questions.

I now find that I am in a position to answer at least two more questions, but the system tells me: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account."

If I look at my details, I can see no rejected answers, or in fact, anything negative.

Could someone who knows enlighted a frustrated newcomer? (To Stack Overflow, that is.)

Comment: Are you sure you have only had one answer deleted (the one you mention)?

Comment: In future: use a comment. You can post comments when you reach 50 reputation points.

Comment: Also, minor nit: there is no need to sign posts on SO; your user card is your signature.

Comment: Normal users can't see deleted answers, but you actually had three such comments as answers that were deleted. Two of them were downvoted as well. This could all be contributing to the answer ban, as I commented on Aaron's answer. We've had a few bad users spamming comments like this across the site, so countermeasures like this exist to prevent that. Sorry you got caught up in it before realizing what was going on.

Comment: P.S. if you make some suggested edits I will certainly help push them through (if they're valuable) if you post the links here (or let me know about them some other way). I think you were legitimately using the site but just didn't understand some of the obscure etiquette. Though the FAQ is a really good thing to read before you start posting questions or answers again.

Answer (score 7):

Here is [the question that probably caused the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289032/custom-windows-authentication-package). That was deleted because requests for clarification should be posted as comments, not answers. Sadly you can't do that until you've amassed a bit more rep.

But it shouldn't take much rep to get your asking privileges back. Can you try to post a question or answer now?

If you still can't post, you will need to find other ways to get some rep and earn privileges back. The easiest way to do this is to find poorly worded or formatted questions or answers, click the `edit` link and propose suggested edits. They won't take place immediately and they are subject to peer review. You can read about how to earn reputation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: There were two other deleted answers, both downvoted by someone before being deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165324/reading-from-serial-port-on-ubuntu-linux-11-10-in-c/11297425#11297425 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313235/debugging-web-application/11313292#11313292 , which might be contributing to the problem. Three such comments as answers being deleted, with two of them being downvoted by members of the community, might be enough to trigger the answering ban.

Comment: @Brad good recon, thanks. I'm just a peon so had no easy way to track down the others.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your help, I'm beginning to see the light. Err, not sure I'm supposed to post thanks either :-)